# android- How to avoid tablayout child to load data again

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm using tablayout with ViewPager, I've 3 tabs and I'm using fragment for my tabs . The problem is ,when I go to tab 3 , the content of tab 1 is fully lost and it need to reload again ,I don't want something like this , I want to make them to save the data and it doesn't need to reload again .

this is my code :

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Bundle bl = getIntent().getExtras();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("for", bl.getString("for"));
    if (bl.getString("for").equals("catid"))
        bundle.putString("catid", bl.getString("catid"));

    Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
    bundle2.putString("for", bl.getString("for"));
    if (bl.getString("for").equals("catid"))
        bundle2.putString("catid", bl.getString("catid"));

    Bundle bundle3 = new Bundle();
    bundle3.putString("for", bl.getString("for"));
    if (bl.getString("for").equals("catid"))
        bundle3.putString("catid", bl.getString("catid"));

    FragmentList latest = new FragmentList();
    bundle.putString("forw","latest");
    latest.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentList topvisit = new FragmentList();
    bundle2.putString("forw","topvisit");
    topvisit.setArguments(bundle2);

    FragmentList por_mabhas = new FragmentList();
    bundle3.putString("forw","por_mabhas");
    por_mabhas.setArguments(bundle3);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(por_mabhas, "پرمبحث ترین خبرها");
    adapter.addFragment(topvisit, "پربازدیدترین اخبار");
    adapter.addFragment(latest, "تازه ترین خبرها");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}



private void declare() {
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    final int finalPos = 2;
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int right = ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(finalPos).getRight();
            tabLayout.scrollTo(right,0);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(finalPos).select();
        }
    });
}
```

How can I do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setOffscreenPageLimit(TOTAL_PAGE);` If you have N pages, you can use this, so that it will keep all pages in memory.

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(TOTAL_PAGE);
```

Comment: I would sincerely call this a total mess, the default behavior is efficient and saves much of system resources.

Comment: its only for person who want to load all pages at once.. don't worry bro.. it just a solution to the question..